# SparkR error in Rstudio and Rcmd

Tags: sparkr

head(df)  SparkR error

Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6, localhost): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

```
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRDD$.createRProcess(RRDD.scala:407)

    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRDD$.createRWorker(RRDD.scala:445)

    at org.apache.spark.api.r.BaseRRDD.compute(RRDD.scala:62)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.sc
```

Comment: facing same issue when submitting job to spark cluster spark://master:node. On the other hand while submitting job to local not facing this issue